# Getting hardware error: Processor : microcode 42 on my new laptop

Tags: drivers, kernel, dell, hardware, microcode

I bought a new Dell Inspiron 7650, i7 few days ago and dual booted it with Ubuntu 17.04, alongside Windows 10 that came with it.

I am noticing that whenever I wake up the laptop, for a fraction of a second I see some hardware errors on the ui and just before the unlock screen shows up. 
The error message goes something like this:

```
mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 0: Machine Check: 0 Bank 6: ee2000000040110a
mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC 0 ADDR fef20000 MISC 43880000086
mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 0:806e9 TIME 1493996371 SOCKET 0 APIC 0 microcode 42
mce: [Hardware Error]: CPU 0: Machine Check: 0 Bank 7: ee2000000040110a
mce: [Hardware Error]: TSC 0 ADDR fef20040 MISC 43880000086
mce: [Hardware Error]: PROCESSOR 0:806e9 TIME 1493996371 SOCKET 0 APIC 0 microcode 42
```

I saw that in "additional drivers" there was some Intel microcode driver listed, I also tried installing it but the error message still shows up every time.
What could it be? Is that a hardware issue or kernel?

Here is a photo of the screen:
[image]

**Update:**

I ran all the hardware tests on machine: Dell Support Center tests from windows and the pre-boot tests from BIOS, both pass. Windows event viewer does not show any error logs related to this, when I sleep/wake it. Raised a dell support request, the support person told me that this error is due to some issue with 'drivers' in Ubuntu and happens only when we dual-boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu. I could choose to remove Windows completely and install only Ubuntu, then it should go away and they could schedule a support call for it, but post that the support will be very limited (since Linux!). Also, that they have raised this with Ubuntu developers / Intel and they are working on this issue and I should watch for an update to OS that fixes this (could not get a link to the issue report.)

Essentially, there seems like no solution to this for now. If it is a false positive, is there a way I can at least hide this from showing up on each wake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue seems to have been resolved since the bios update to version: 1.1.1.
My machine's bios was updated primarily for a different [issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/916304/sound-fails-randomly-mostly-when-headphones-are-connected) which still persists though.