# Have a question about dual booting?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I just recently purchased a new laptop, a Dell Inspiron 15-3567. It has an core i3 processor, 6 Gb of ram, and 1 Tb hard drive. I wanted to dual boot windows with ubuntu 16.04.3, but have run into some issues.

Now, first thing i did was, is I went into the BIOS and went to change the boot sequence, because i was going to run ubuntu from a disk. I changed it to UEFI secure boot off, made sure the legacy boot was off, and then applied changes and restarted. Once I restarted, I went back into the BIOS and I set it to boot from the disk drive. It restarted and then booted into the ubuntu disk. Everything was working fine, I did see however that it said hardware issue, when the disk was first initializing, but it seemed to boot fine and brought up the try free or install ubuntu prompt window.

So, I hit install ubuntu and went through the motions, because I was sure it would tell me soon that I already had a os on the machine and what would I like to do. So, when I got to that prompt, it said that ubuntu didnt detect any os and how would i like to proceed. Well, I canceled the install, and then backed out and shutdown the laptop. Once i rebooted, I went back into the BIOS, and changed the settings back, and I still have my windows 10 that came on the laptop; so I'm thoroughly confused on how that happened. Anyone know what Im doing wrong ?

Comment: whatwas the hardware issue?

Comment: Im not sure, but I can try it again then i find out what it says; but i did go to a canicol site that stated the specs for the laptops its compatible with and i didnt see my laptop on there lol.

Comment: that does not mean that it is incompatable. ubuntu runs on many more laptops than what is listed

Comment: Make sure you have the Windows fast start up off. And only use Windows to shrink the NTFS partition. On my Dell 3647 SFF system, I also made 3 backups, Dell, Windows, & a full image with Macrium. Multiple flash drives and couple of DVDs.  Then only use Something Else to install. While you can add the Linux partition(s) during install, I prefer to use gparted first to create them. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2364642 & https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN301754/how-to-install-ubuntu-and-a-recent-windows-operating-system-as-a-dual-boot-on-your-dell-pc?lang=EN

Comment: @ravery, the hardware issue maybe what is described in https://askubuntu.com/questions/914653/getting-hardware-error-processor-microcode-42-on-my-new-laptop.

Comment: It's often necessary to use the manual partitioning ("something else") installation option on EFI-based computers when dual-booting with Windows. Also, as Hildy says, you should be sure that Fast Startup is [disabled](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-10-a.html) in Windows. For more on doing the manual partitioning, see [this question and its answers.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation)

Answer (score 1):

It is slightly possible that you need to disable a feature in Windows called "Fast Startup." It's just something that Windows does to log the state of certain things in the Windows OS to help it boot faster. I have seen in a few dual-boot tutorials where they say that it's best to turn that off.

In Windows: right click the battery icon in the tray, select power options, select choose what power buttons do, select change setting that are currently unavailable, and uncheck fast startup.

There's at least a chance this will help at best, and it's a good practice at worst.

Comment: Well, I tried what you said, and its still showing up that there is no operating system. I couldnt get a good pic of the Hardware error I was getting, but I believe it was just the ubuntu os not recognizing my hardware.

Comment: Man, sorry that didn't help. But, I do know that it is proper procedure, so it doesn't hurt to know. I will, however, give you a link here to a video about dual boot installations using a thumb stick. It couldn't hurt to give it a try, maybe it's the disk drive process that has flaw. Fast forward to 1:06:50. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wBp0Rb-ZJak